# Android Google Maps error (nControl = mapView.getController();)

Tags: android

I've have Google API 16 loaded
Compiling with Google API 16

Error for this line is "mapView cannot be resolved"

```
  <nControl = mapView.getController();>
```

Have deleted gen folder, done a clean
Have restarted Eclipse
Any help would be greatly appreciated as I new to this and trying to make a map for a non-profit

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:apiKey="AIzaSyC1r4MzsV6jc2J-g335UlIN8WYS6D3hJks"
/>
```

**GoogleMaps3.manifest**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="net.example.googlemaps3.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <user-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 package net.example.googlemaps3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MapController nControl;
GeoPoint GeoP;
MapView mapV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     mapV = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
     mapV.displayZoomControls(true);
        mapV.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        double lat=44.3;
        double Longi=-79.8;
        GeoP= new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1E6),(int)(Longi*1E6));            
        nControl = mapView.getController();
        nControl.animateTo(GeoP);
        nControl.setZoom(12);   
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your variable is `mapV` and not `mapView`, you should continue on that path and rewrite

```
nControl = mapView.getController();
```

as

```
nControl = mapV.getController();
```